# Cant Get Image In API22 Device From Back4App

Tags: android, ssl, parse-platform

I am trying to get Images From Parse and show in Listview.

I am Using **Back4App** As APP backend.

To Load Images I am Using **ImageLoader**

**Now Problem is:**

When I am Run On **API23** device Its show Image In Listview . Its Work Perfectly.

But When I am Run On **4.4.4 , 5.0 ,5.1** Devices Its Not Load Image.

**Its Show Something error Like this :**

Caused by: **javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb4068400: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error**

I Dont Know Why this Problem I am Facing.

Comment: Its bug from Server side now its fixed

Answer (score 0):

sometimes is a error related with the date from your device!
At Setting -> Date & Time -> Check Automatic date & time .